# What is the canonical way to redefine the \emph command

Tags: formatting, emphasis

Question says it all. What is the best way to redefine the `\emph` command to be bold font and upright?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since `\emph` uses `\em`, I would redefine `\em`.

Here's such a redefinition which preserves the ability to toggle between bold and normal, if nested:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\em}{%
  \@nomath\em \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil
  \normalfont \else \bfseries \fi}
\makeatother
```

Test of nesting behavior of `\emph`:

```
Question: \emph{What is the way to redefine the \emph{\textbackslash emph} command?}
```

[image]

Comment: @Stefan: +1 for reminding me of `\em`'s toggling ability.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes any sense to use normal font to *emphasise* something inside bold text...

Comment: @Jukka: I just imitated the toggling. Of course `\normalfont` may be replaced by `\itshape` or the like if accumulation of font attributes would be preferred. Toggling allows unworried nesting, accumulation does not.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks. Not part of the original question but how can one save the old `\em`? `\let\oldem\em` does not seem to have an effect.

Comment: @Yiannis: yes, and neither does `\xdef`. Perhaps copy& paste ... or define `\em` to be variable: using `\noemphasizing` and `\emphasizing` and a test macro instead of `\upshape` and `\itshape`. This way one just has to change the simple macros instead of redefining `\em` again.

Comment: @Stefan Both are great answers!

Comment: @Yiannis: If you do `\show\em`, you will get `\protect \em  .` in the log file and notice the two spaces after `\em` (they do not show here for some reason): this is because it is a protected macro and so the original definition is saved in the `\csname em \endcsname` macro. So you should do `\expandafter\let\expandafter\oldem\csname em \endcsname`. Just beware that `\oldem` is not a protected macro anymore.

Comment: Note that the toggling is somewhat modified by `fixltx2e` so that in an italic context, `\em` produces `\eminnershape` (by default this is `\upshape` to give the original behaviour, but it can be redefined to, eg, `\scshape` to give small caps).

Comment: @Philippe: just a thought: it is also possible to do `\begingroup\def\protect{\global\let\oldem}\em\endgroup`.

Comment: And what If we wanted to use `\slshape` instead of `\bfseries` (in this example). I want to emphasize in slanted. How would the redefinition be?

Comment: @Manuel `\makeatletter\DeclareRobustCommand\em{\@nomath\em \ifdim \fontdimen\@ne\font >\z@\upshape \else \slshape \fi}\makeatother`

Answer (score 19):

According to p. 194 of the [LaTeX2e sources](http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf), `\emph` is defined as

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\em}
```

So I suggest to redefine it as follows:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\bfseries}
```

Comment: This won't toggle like `\emph` does, though, correct?  I don't know if that's part of the OP's idea of "canonical."

Comment: @Matthew: It won't, and I already admitted as much.

Comment: @Matthew I normally use the word `canonical` to mean ...how do you think Lamport would have written it? Not exactly from the Oxford Dictionary :)