# Non-italic \emph, italic biblatex titles

Tags: macros, biblatex, italic, emphasis

The internal Biblatex `\mkbibemph` macro defaults to being an alias for `\emph` (see section 4.10.4 *Auxiliary Commands and Hooks* in its documentation).
It is used with `\DeclareFieldFormat` to typeset certain fields, especially *title*, in many bibliography styles.

I [redefined `\em`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6754/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-redefine-the-emph-command) and thereby `\emph`, however, because I cannot use italics for emphasis in text. Italics are required in citation titles, though (which I would not consider emphasis, by the way).

Which is the correct way to redefine `\mkbibemph` to use either `\textit` or `\itshape`?

1. `\renewcommand{\mkbibemph}[1]{\textit{#1}}`
2. `\renewcommand{\mkbibemph}{\textit}`
3. `\let\mkbibemph\textit`
4. `\def\mkbibemph{\textit}`
5. something else

Comment: The default definition is `\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibemph}{\emph}`. So you can do the same.

Comment: Variant `4` wouldn't work, it needed be `\def\mkbibemph{\textit}` ;) @MarcoDaniel make it an answer. Btw, does `\renewrobustcmd*` exists? Is there an existence check? If so, one might need to `\let\mkbibemph\relax` or `\let\mkbibemph\@undefined` first, might not he?

Comment: `\renewrobustcmd*` does compile at least. Like the other solutions, it doesn’t work in my actual document, though, and I’m still trying to figure out why. As a workaround, I can redefine `\em` again just before the bibliography.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case I think the command in biblatex is not very well chosen: If a citation requires the title to be in italics, it should just do so. The thing about `\emph` is, that it may toggle if necessary. It is probably best to create a new wrapper for a custom `\emph` command in the text of a custom `\mkbibit` for the bibliography. In the latter case you have of course to redefine the whole style you use :(

Comment: The 'toggle'-like nature of `\emph` should be kept in italic titles: If my book title includes the title of another work, then the title-in-title should be set in the original typeface (presumably Roman/upright).  E.g., imagine a (book) title like: *Soliloquies and Other Nonesense in Shakespeare's* Hamlet.  In fact, I'd suggest not redefining `\em` (or `\emph`), but defining your own semantic mark-up command for how you want to emphasize things.  Doing so is more in line with separating form and content anyway.

Comment: `\emph` is how I want to emphasize things (be it by italics or otherwise). `\mkbibemph` is accompanied by `\mkbibbold` in biblatex, not `\mkbibstrong`, which is saying something. `\mkbibitalic` is being added, now. Whether double italic should result in something else there, is a different question.

Comment: Yes, it is a 'style guide' question; but I strongly doubt you will find a guide that recommends 'double italics' should be set in italics (or worse bold). The emphasized form of italics is regular text. Thus, `\mkbibemph` inside `\mkbibemph` should do what a nested `\emph` does, which is switch back to 'regular' emphsis. This is completely lost if you use `\textit` (or `\mkbibitalic`) as the title font -- *even if* your view is that emphasized text in italics should be set in bold or some other monstrosity.  Who wants to read *Soliloquies and Other Nonesense in Shakespeare's **Hamlet***?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [`biblatex`’s Github](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/189):

```
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibitalic}{\textit}
\protected\long\def\blx@imc@mkbibemph#1{%
  \textit{#1}\blx@imc@setpunctfont\textit}
\makeatother

\let\mkbibemph\mkbibitalic
```

If you’re reading this in my distant future, `biblatex` may already ship with a `\mkbibitalic` macro, then the last line would suffice, of course.

Comment: The distant future is here.