# How to redefine \emph to have bold text with bold math?

Tags: formatting, emphasis

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6754/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-redefine-the-emph-command) explains how to redefine the `\emph` command so that the text is bold. When mathematical text is included with emphasized text, I have been using the following solution:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here the mathematical text is not bold: \\

\noindent An \emph{$n$-dimensional chart} of a topological space $M$ is a pair
$(U,\mathbf{x})$,  where $U$ is an open subset of $M$ and $\mathbf{x}: M \supset U 
\to \mathbf{x}(U)\subset \mathbf{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism. \\

\noindent Here is the corrected version: \\

\noindent An \emph{$\bm{n}$-dimensional chart} of a topological space $M$ is a pair 
$(U,\mathbf{x})$, where $U$ is an open subset of $M$ and $\mathbf{x}: M \supset U \to 
\mathbf{x}(U)\subset \mathbf{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism. 

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

My question is: how can you further redefine `\emph` so that mathematical text is automatically bold, using `\bm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `\boldmath`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\boldmath\bfseries}

\begin{document}

Here the mathematical text is bold:

An \emph{$n$-dimensional chart} of a topological space $M$ is a pair $(U,\mathbf{x})$,
where $U$ is an open subset of $M$ and $\mathbf{x}: M \supset U \to \mathbf{x}(U)\subset
\mathbf{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now that you know how, please, refrain from using boldface for emphasis, particularly if you use mathematics in it.

You seem to have a habit of using `\\` at the end of paragraphs: avoid it.

Comment: Why shouldn't you use boldface for emphasis? It's pretty common in differential geometry books. And I don't normally use \\ after paragraphs, just for this example.

Comment: @RandyRanderson It is too prominent; and when there is math in it, your readers could misunderstand symbols, particularly if you're using bold ones.

Comment: I didn't think about that, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Also, instead of repeatedly using `\noindent` you could just use `\usepackage{parskip}`

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to load `bm`, provided `\emph` be used outside mathmode:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\bfseries\boldmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here the mathematical text is bold: \\

\noindent An \emph{$n$-dimensional chart} of a topological space $M$ is a pair $(U,\mathbf{x})$,
where $U$ is an open subset of $M$ and $\mathbf{x}: M \supset U \to \mathbf{x}(U)\subset
\mathbf{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism. \\

\noindent To compare with the hand-made version: \\

\noindent An \emph{$\bm{n}$-dimensional chart} of a topological space $M$ is a pair $(U,\mathbf{x})$,
where $U$ is an open subset of $M$ and $\mathbf{x}: M \supset U \to \mathbf{x}(U)\subset
\mathbf{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism.

\end{document}
```

[image]